# Css multiple class selector .class1.class2 not working

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to select an element with multiple classes.

```
.parent1 .subparent2 .class1,
.parent1 .subparent2 .class2,
.parent1 .subparent2 .class3 { }
```

As

```
.parent1 .subparent2 .class1.class2.class3
```

to select an element with all three classes but it doesn't work.

Comment: That is how you do it (at least the second part, the first doesn't make much sense). Show us your markup.

Comment: `.class1.class2.class3` is correct. Can you show your HTML? Also IE6 (and newer IE in quirks mode) don't support it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have works, *if the browser supports it*, [you can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/4z9C4/).  Here's my test markup:

```
<div class="parent1">
    <div class="subparent2">
        <div class="class1 class2 class3">Match</div>
        <div class="class1 class2">No Match</div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

With your current selector:

```
.parent1 .subparent2 .class1.class2.class3 { color:red; }​
```

---

*Based on comments:* To be clear, the two selectors are not equivalent, this:

```
.parent1 .subparent2 .class1, .parent1 .subparent2 .class2 ...
```

Means that the child can have *any of the classes* and match, but this:

```
.parent1 .subparent2 .class1.class2.class3
```

Means the child has to have **all of the classes** to match, so they serve different purposes.

Comment: I tried this exactly this does not work. So I am sticking with the first option.

Comment: @mrNepal - I think I understand the confusion now, the first and second selectors are not equivalent, the first selects where the child has *any* of the three classes, the `.class1.class2.class3` version means it has to have **all** of the classes, is that what isn't clear?